# How to chain promises for multiple ajax calls to SharePoint to get user ids?

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, jquery, promises

Broken promises, thought I had it figured out, still trying to get reliable results. Console log shows hit and miss results. Below is the rundown of what I'm trying to achieve. Is there a simpler way to do this, I've been struggling with this for a week now just to update person fields, its ridiculous.

- I have 2 multiperson people pickers in SharePoint.
- MS gives you every user detail EXCEPT the user id which is needed to update via ajax
- I can get the emails from the people pickers into arrays
- My promises setup is hit and miss retrieving id's
- When it works it outputs a string array that doesn't work with updating field

  eg: 1,2,3,4 instead of [1,2,3,4]

function test1a() {

```
    fEmailArray = [];
    tEmailArray = [];
    fIdArray = [];
    tIdArray = [];

    var FCon = $("div[title='From Contacts'] > input").val();
    var Fjson = JSON.parse(FCon);
    for (var i = 0; i < Fjson.length; i++) {
        fEmailArray.push(Fjson[i].EntityData.Email);
    }

    var TCon = $("div[title='To Contacts'] > input").val();
    var Tjson = JSON.parse(TCon);
    for (var i = 0; i < Tjson.length; i++) {
        tEmailArray.push(Tjson[i].EntityData.Email);
    }

    let promiseF = fEmailArray.map(fEmail => test2(fEmail));
    let promiseT = tEmailArray.map(tEmail => test2(tEmail));

    return Promise.all(promiseF)
        .then(function (data) { fIdArray = data; })
        .then(Promise.all(promiseT)
        .then(function (data) { tIdArray = data; }));            
}

function test2(xEmail) {

    let myPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        $.ajax({ // get the Ids of users
            url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/SiteUsers?$select=Id&$filter=Email eq '" + xEmail + "'",
            type: "GET", headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose", },
            success: function (data) {
                var xuserid = data.d.results[0].Id;
                resolve(xuserid);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(error));
                reject();
            }
        });
    });
    return myPromise;
} // end test2
```

Comment: A big problem is the array output is string, instead of numeric ids.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice here would be to use JSOM, load all the queries that you need and then execute your function once it's done, so then you don't need to worry about timing.

Below is an example:

```
var currentUser;
function init(){
 this.clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
 this.oWeb = clientContext.get_web();
 currentUsers = this.oWeb.get_currentUser();
 this.clientContext.load(currentUsers); /* you do it for all 
 the users you need to load */
 this.clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
 function(){
   /*Here you can access your whole query's result at once.
   use currentUsers.getEnumerator(); to convert the result to a 
   list.*/
 })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about it returning strings... I did a bunch of playing around with this, and all I ever got was integers.

Now, one thing you could do, if you wanted to keep your `ajax` call wrapped in a `Promise` as you have it now, is to combine all the requests/promises into one big array so that you have only one `Promise.all()` and are not chaining those:

```
let promiseF = fEmailArray.map(fEmail => test2(fEmail));
let promiseT = tEmailArray.map(tEmail => test2(tEmail));

let fBatchLength = promiseF.length;

// expand both promise arrays into one array so you only have
// one Promise.all() - the results will preserve the order!
return Promise.all([...promiseF, ...promiseT])
    .then(function (data) {

        // you know your "f"s were first, so pull them out using splice
        fIdArray = data.splice(0, fBatchLength);

        // splice actually changes the original array, so
        // there's nothing left in data except the "t"s
        tIdArray = data;

        // you return your Promise.all, so is it fair to say
        // that the code that called function test1a() is expecting
        // a result?  if so you need to return something out of the then()
        return {
            fIDs: fIdArray,
            tIDs: tIdArray
        };
    });
```

However, `$.ajax()` returns a deferred object, which is kind of like a promise, so you could unwrap your `ajax` call from the other promises and just return that, and deal with digging the IDs out of the results in your main function.  So `test2` would turn into:

```
function test2(xEmail) {
    return $.ajax({ // get the Ids of users
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/SiteUsers?$select=Id&$filter=Email eq '" + xEmail + "'",
        type: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose", },
    });
}
```

and in the main function you could do:

```
let promiseF = fEmailArray.map(fEmail => test2(fEmail));
let promiseT = tEmailArray.map(tEmail => test2(tEmail));

let fBatchLength = promiseF.length;

// expand both promise arrays into one array so you only have
// one Promise.all() - the results will preserve the order!
return Promise.all([...promiseF, ...promiseT])
    .then(function (data) {

        // deal with the ajax responses
        var allIDs = data.map(function(response) {
            return response.d.results[0].Id;
        });

        // you know your "f"s were first, so pull them out using splice
        fIdArray = allIDs.splice(0, fBatchLength);

        // splice actually changes the original array, so
        // there's nothing left in allIDs except the "t"s
        tIdArray = allIDs;

        // you return your Promise.all, so is it fair to say
        // that the code that called function test1a() is expecting
        // a result?  if so you need to return something out of the then()
        return {
            fIDs: fIdArray,
            tIDs: tIdArray
        };
    });
```

I think either way the main thing is to get away from the chained `Promise.all`s.